# Changing version for a transitive dependency in gradle

Tags: java, scala, gradle

I have a very weird requirement of using two different version for scala library.

The scenario is that there are some very old tests are using scala library with a very older version and now when have created new Kafka Consumers and producers in the same package and scala transitively gets the latest version of scala.

Is there a way I can run old tests on older version and new tests on newer version for scala.

Comment: Question isn't specific to Kafka. You can use build profiles for running different test suites. This is done all the time in maven. I'm sure something similar is done in Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I can share what we did for downgrading the Scala dependency when we used an older version of Spring Kafka in a Spring Boot context:

```java
dependencies {
  constraints {
    testImplementation('org.scala-lang:scala-library') {
      // See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/1623
      // This can be removed if upgrading Spring Kafka to 2.6
      because('There is a transitive dependency from Jackson to Scala that is not compatible with the version required by Apache Kafka')
      version {
        strictly '2.12.11'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will force the scala-library dependency to be a specific version for all tests.

If you want to run some tests in one version and some in another, and they are all in the same module, you are probably better of segregating your tests in different source sets. You can read about this in the user guide [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests) (though about integration testing, the same principle applies to other kinds of tests.)